# How to increment value in MySQL with PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have a integer column in a MySQL table called `col1`. Now, what I need is to increase its value by some number say 1 (maybe 2, 3 or anything). i.e. If it was already holding value of 10, now I want it to become 11. I know, I can do it by first selecting the original value, increment it with PHP and then update the value. But I wanted to know if there is a way through which I don't have to select the previous value to increment it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done very simply, just execute a query like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET col1=col1+1 WHERE key=99";
```

Or any value you like

```
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET col1=col1+3 WHERE key=99";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a table with a single record used for multiple counters.

1. Manually create a table called `counts` with a single `Int` column, named `myCount`.
   <sub><sup>(Later, add more **Int** columns for additional counters.)</sup></sub>
   ie., `CREATE TABLE counts (myCount int);`
2. manually insert a single record with a value of `0` for column `myCount`.
   <sub><sup>(Never add more records, just use this one for all your counters.)</sup></sub>
   ie., `INSERT INTO counts (myCount) VALUES (0);`

Then, run this code each time you want to increment counter `myCount` by one:

```php
<?php
  require_once('connect.php');
  $cn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if(!$cn->connect_error){$cn->query("UPDATE counts SET myCount=myCount+1");}
?>
```

- [`connect.php`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTv16.png) is a simple connection info file.
- This code (intentionally) **produces no output**, even if there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query to update.

```
$sql = "update your_table
set col1= col1 + (some number)
where id = (some condition)";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use update query. Example

```
$update_sql = "update tablename set col1 = col1 + 1 where id = 1";
```

(ID may be any unique key value of a row in your MySQL table for which the value is to be incremented)